# Couchbase, 4 nodes with replicas (not sharding), select from 127.0.0.1

Tags: python, python-2.7, couchbase

We have cluster with 4 nodes and need:

1. failing any node - no "pending" state of cluster
2. all data in all nodes - no sharding, only replication to all nodes
3. read ALWAYS from local node

### How to do it?

UP: Why we need read local:
6-nodes cluster with 1 node down, select data from python:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/couchbase/connection.py", line 500, in get
    return _Base.get(self, key, ttl, quiet, replica, no_format)
couchbase.exceptions._NetworkError_0x10 (generated, catch NetworkError): <Key=u'configuration!ivr.conf!ivr_000*308@siptest.ringme.ru', RC=0x10[Network failure], Operational Error, Results=1, C Source=(src/multiresult.c,282)>

Replicas: 2 copies

couchbase on this error MUST read another nodes on error!
```

Answer (score 3):

Couchbase does provide efficient sharding and replicas mechanism. So your #2 "no sharding" will be alien to Couchbase (but achievable via [XCDR](http://blog.couchbase.com/tag/xdcr))

Therefore, if you have 4 physical nodes with CB server instance on each I recommend the following setup (to achieve under 1 millisecond access times and HA 24/7 setup):

1. Join all 4 instances into one cluster so you have real HA setup (if node is down, operations have no interruption and its transparent to the client)
2. When you define each bucket (type Couchbase) provide 3 replicas to be kept on the other nodes (so each node will have all data) See [Couchbase Data Storage](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.5/cb-admin/#data-storage).
3. I assume that your client application is remote to the Couchbase cluster on a 5th server. So you will have to supply list of all 4 server IPs and port numbers where CB is running on (this is needed only for client start-up to obtain cluster configuration and subscribe to cluster changes).

If you implement above steps, you will achieve fault tolerant setup for 24/7 non-stop operations where data is kept on all 4 nodes (its like [RAID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID))

Comment: What if we put 10 nodes and need full data set on all nodes?
If we put 3 nodes with "2 replicas", and 1 node is gone, cluster will continue to work or switches to "pending state"? (i catch pending state, where in 3-nodes config one node died)

Comment: Replicas are handled on a background. Cluster continues to function. In your example of 10 nodes, it doesn't make sense to have 9 replicas - since it will consume too much resources/bandwidth to keep data replicated. Instead I think CD has limit of 3 replicas that should give you plenty of room for failure....for example in your 10 node cluster you can afford 3 nodes down simultaneously (with replication factor of 3).

Comment: > Join all 4 instances into one cluster so you have real HA setup (if node is down, operations have no interruption and its transparent to the client) ---- False, see UP

Answer (score 0):

user1697575's answer covers most of your questions, but on point (3) - "read always from local node" - why do you want to do this?

You can't really do this in a cluster which has >1 node, as the data is automatically distributed (sharded) across all nodes, and there's no way to disable sharing.

Comment: > why do you want to do this?
1) less network traffic, less latency
2) if node has gone away - another nodes must continue work, but without rebalance, it is not so (timeouts, etc)

> as the data is automatically distributed (sharded) across all nodes, and there's no way to disable sharing
we need replication, but not sharding (full data set on all nodes)

Comment: Its not debate about sharding vs replication. Couchbase has both - sharding at its core to provide low latency and data distribution/even load and replication to provide HA/failover.